# How to get sum over time horizont and different names from dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy, math

Let's say I have a couple of dictionaries (one per hour) which all have the same keys:

```
h1={'a':1, 'b':3, 'c':10}
h2={'a':7, 'b':15, 'c':2}
h3={'a':9, 'b':15, 'c':35}
```

How can I get the sum of absolute values between the next hours for all hours and keys, meaning a sum of the form:

```
|1-7|+|7-9|+|3-15|+|15-15|+|10-2|+|2-35|
```

more generally it is something of the form:

[image]

where beta is 1, the psts are the keys of our dictionary and we also sum over hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using numpy, you can craft an array, compute the absolute difference ([`numpy.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)+`abs`), and `sum`:

```
h1={'a':1, 'b':3, 'c':10}
h2={'a':7, 'b':15, 'c':2}
h3={'a':9, 'b':15, 'c':35}

import numpy as np
dicts = [h1, h2, h3]

a = np.array([list(d.values()) for d in dicts])
abs(np.diff(a, axis=0)).sum()
```

output: `61`

With beta:

```
beta = 1
abs(np.diff(a, axis=0)*beta).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably better to use `pandas` than `numpy` for this.
Pretty sure it would just be

```
beta = 1
pd.DataFrame([h1, h2, h3]).diff().dropna().abs().mul(beta).sum().sum()
Out: 61.0
```

Comment: Why would `pandas` be better than `numpy`? `numpy` is about 2 orders of magnitude faster ;)

Comment: @mozway Mostly because it's easy to keep track of catgorical data (such as dicts) that way.  I've learned the hard way that sometimes human-readable organization beats raw speed. :)